# How to add a right click menu event to a md-tab with angular2/4 material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have the following code:

```
<md-tab-group>
  <md-tab label="MyLabel">
    <ng-template md-tab-label>
      MyLabel <md-icon>thumb_down</md-icon>
    </ng-template>    
    Content
   </md-tab>
  <md-tab label="MyLabel">
    <ng-template md-tab-label>
      MyLabel <md-icon>thumb_down</md-icon>
    </ng-template>    
    Content
   </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

I want to make it such that I can right click on a tab, and show a little menu that I can select "Bookmark" and have it log out the label of the md-tab on in the console. Is this possible? How can it be achieved?

Comment: Have you tried any thing?

Comment: You can try [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-contextmenu) though. They have provided a demo as well. That should work with your `<md-tab>` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Putting a `(contextmenu)` event binding on the mat-tab itself doesn't work but you can put it on a div inside the mat-tab-label template.

See [MatMenuTrigger](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview#toggling-the-menu-programmatically) for how you can toggle a menu programmatically. That can then be toggled from within your event handler.

See working example here: [Working example of tab with context menu](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r3ag77?file=src/app/tab-group-basic-example.html)